# express.Router() vs express() in express

Tags: node.js, express

As mentioned in express [routing guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734383/109747), we can create "mini-app" and `use` it from the main app. However I saw a code where it uses `app` instead of `router` in the module

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

var app = express();

app.use('/user', userRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

**routes/user.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); // not express.Router() !!

app.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
  var userName = req.params.name;
  res.render('user.jade', {
    userName: userName
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I assumed the correct usage in `routes/user.js` should be

```
router = express.Router()
```

instead of

```
app = express()
```

but `app = express()` also works! what are the differences and why `router = express.Router()` is better?

Answer (score 3):

When you are working with a server where there are many routes, it can be confusing to leave them in a Main file together. The `let router = express.Router()` option works differently than `let app = express()`.

While the `app` returns an app object, `router` will return a small app fragment, similar to the `app`, where you will use logic to call them later on the Main.

**The most important**, about your question, is that a `router`, which is isolated, **will not interfere with others** in the application, being a single environment.

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

> A router object is an isolated instance of middleware and routes. You can think of it as a “mini-application,” capable only of performing middleware and routing functions. Every Express application has a built-in app router.
>
> A router behaves like middleware itself, so you can use it as an argument to app.use() or as the argument to another router’s use() method.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by interference? What kind of interference an `app` has? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: When you create a test environment, for example, it's much easier to handle errors and refactor code in standalone environments. About the router, a great example is the middlewares. You can create a middleware to be used on all routes of a router without interfering with other routers. Of course, you could even do this individually by each single route, but I don't think it's an appropriate approach to facilitate maintenance and reading.